# How to change dates in column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a problem with Pandas, Python. I have several rows with different dates, where the dates are String

```
"2016-02-28"   ABC123
"2016-02-29"   CDE345
"2016-03-30"   FGH567
"2016-03-31"   XYZ235
...
```

Here we see that feb has two different days, 28 and 29. I am only interested in the month. Thus, I want these rows to have the same day, like this:

```
"2016-02-29"   ABC123
"2016-02-29"   CDE345
"2016-03-31"   FGH567
"2016-03-31"   XYZ235
...
```

It does not really matter which day they get, as long as it is the same day but preferable the last day. I cannot truncate and only keep "2016-02" because I later need the day. I can convert it timestamp if it becomes easier.

```
df ["DATE"] = pandas.to_datetime (df ["DATE"])
```

(Another question, why does this line convert the DATE column to Timestamp instead of datetime?? It says to convert to datetime, but instead it becomes Timestamp?)

I have tried to resample, but to no avail. I dont want to do this manually, by cutting and pasting Strings as I have done earlier. There should be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) offset:

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime (df["DATE"]) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
print (df)
        DATE     COL
0 2016-02-29  ABC123
1 2016-02-29  CDE345
2 2016-03-31  FGH567
3 2016-03-31  XYZ235
```

If really big DataFrame and performance is important:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"]).values.astype('datetime64[M]') + \
                            np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') - \
                            np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
print (df)
        DATE     COL
0 2016-02-29  ABC123
1 2016-02-29  CDE345
2 2016-03-31  FGH567
3 2016-03-31  XYZ235
```

---

> (Another question, why does this line convert the DATE column to
>   Timestamp instead of datetime?? It says to convert to datetime, but
>   instead it becomes Timestamp?)

If you see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) it says :

> TimeStamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is
>   interchangable with it in most cases. It’s the type used for the
>   entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented
>   data structures in pandas.

Comment: @Bharath - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or we using `to_period`

```
df.index=df.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')
df
Out[16]: 
                 A
2016-02-29  ABC123
2016-02-29  CDE345
2016-03-31  FGH567
2016-03-31  XYZ235
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however, your solution assumes that Period is the index. I dont want to change my index, so I choose the other solution as it applies better to my problem. But thanx anyway! :)